# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken does not get triggered - Push Notifications not working

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I've spent hours now trying to figure out why `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is not being called.
It worked before. I didn't touch it in weeks. Now stopped working.

Here's my setup:

1. Got `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` sitting in `SceneDelegate`
2. Have declared `SceneDelegate` to be the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`
3. I'm setting `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` in `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)`
4. I'm calling `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization { granted, error in...`   from one of the UIViewControllers in my App, specifically in `viewDidLoad` of that Controller - I get the Authorization Pop-up and when accepting I get a `true` back for `granted`
5. Within `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in ...` a check for `settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized` returns `true`
6. Push Notifications are added as a capability for the App in "Signing & Capabilities" and the entitlement file has been created. I've even already deleted and re-created the entitlement file - just to be sure...
7. I've made sure to run the app on a real device (both via Xcode as well as via TestFlight) - so the delegate not being called is not related to the App running in the Simulator.
8. Have checked if `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` gets called instead at least - but it doesn't.
9. I have tried with a second physical device which I have never used for testing before.
10. I've even checked the status of the APNS Sandbox here: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/
11. The `didReceive` delegate gets called though if I'm sending a test notification to simulator via terminal command `xcrun simctl push...` and I'm getting the notification.
12. Provisioning profile is managed by Xcode and the specified AppID is configured for Push Notifications. Certificates are set up in apple developer account.

Here's how I'm requesting Authorization from the user within `viewDidLoad` of one of my Apps UIViewControlles

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if (granted) {
                    //self.processInitialAPNSRegistration()
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "pushNotificationsEnabled")
                }
                print("permission granted?: \(granted)")
            }
        }
```

And here's the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` delegate method sitting inside `SceneDelegate`. Note: I'm also setting `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` in `scene willConnectTo and declared`SceneDelegate`to implement the`UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol.

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format:"%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken GOT CALLED - APNS TOKEN IS: \(token)")

        self.apiService.setAPNSToken(apnsToken: token, completion: {result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let resultString):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "apnsToken")
                    print(resultString, " TOKEN IS: \(token)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("AN ERROR OCCURED: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })

    }
```

Whatever I do, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is not getting triggered. I'm running out of ideas on what is going wrong.

Where is the error? How can I get `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` to execute again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have gone wrong in the second step `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` delegates are available in `UIApplicationDelegate` **not** in `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

Add `UIApplicationDelegate` to your `SceneDelegate` class and in `willConnectTo` function set the delegate as:

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate = self
```

I hope this works... let me know if you still see an issue.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error. Your suggestions did fix my problem. The bounty is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you use the right provisioning profile which is using a push notification enabled AppId? This one is missing in your steps.

As I am not eligible to put comments yet, posting this in answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I've done that. I did follow these instructions here step by step: https://medium.com/@ufukatalca/generate-apns-certificate-for-ios-push-notifications-ada9234d4c09 I've just updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Problem still remains though. Any other idea?

Comment: Check app settings, whether push notifications are enabled or not. If enabled you can see an option to allow or don't allow.

Comment: Do you mean my point 5 above? If not, can you please describe what you mean in more detail?

Comment: yes somewhat, I asked you to verify from device settings, check app settings to see push notifications enabled or not. Try off and on once.

Comment: This is what I said I already did in point 6. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Was this what you meant?